# How to see py and pyc in robot framework RIDE

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide

How can I see *.py and *.pyc in RIDE (robot framework ide)?

Does ride support them?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RIDE only supports text (*.txt, or *.robot), TSV (tab separated values), and HTML files.

The .py or .pyi files are on our wish list.

The .pyc does not make any sense to open in an Editor, they are byte code.